# Why do i get "Invalid literal for int() with base 10" here?

Tags: python, integer, literals

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`
is what I recieve upon the first entering of the A grade value of paper in a paper size in mm converter (using pycharm), the program runs all the way through once and returns values of `x` and `y` which is strange considering no part of the program should be different the second time round:

```py
run_again = True
while run_again == True:
    x = 210 #x is the short edge
    k = 2**0.5 #sqrt(2)
    grade = int(input("Grade A:"))
    if grade > 4: #page smaller than A4
        recur = grade - 4
        for i in range(recur):
            x = (x*k)/2
            y = x*k
    elif grade < 4: #page larger than A4
        recur = 4 - grade
        y=2*x
        x=x*k
    elif grade==4:
        y=x*k
    x=round(x, 2)
    y=round(y, 2)
    print("{0}mm x {1}mm".format(x, y))
```

Screen shot of this program:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIv6v.png

the logic of the program seems sound, but this error needs working around,
appreciate any help

Comment: Regarding the output, you didn't write anything when asking a grade, and anything can't be converted to an empty string

Comment: Show program input/output, error messages and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or external link.

Comment: I think your problem here is how are you running the program. Probably PyCharm is adding characters to the terminal between each loop. I ran your program on my system: Linux, Python 3.8.5, and I didn't ran into any issues

Comment: Can you try running your code like: `python A4conv.py` in a terminal (command line)? I think that should give you the output you are expecting

Comment: Add try catch block and check. `user_input=input("Grade A:") 

try:
    grade = int(user_input.strip())
except ValueError as ve:
    print(ve)
    print(user_input, len(user_input))`

Comment: Aaaah, I tried this and quickly realized the problem is the faulty return key (and backspace) on my Logitech G502, often a single key press of Enter will register as 2 key presses which is why this empty input gives this error, as when pressing enter for the first result my keyboard provides zero input the second time.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion though, stupid me tbh. I'm new to python haha it's obvious new I think about it

Answer (score 0):

It seems the reason why the program crashed was because nothing was inputed the second time. :)

Before typing nothing:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQYK6.png)

After typing nothing:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrKkQ.png)

Comment: No problem! Good luck on your program! I bet it will turn out great! :)